# How to get current state var value inside useEffect that runs on mount only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [n, setN] = useSTate(0);

useEffect(() => {

  const int_id = setInterval(() => {
     const newN = getN(...);

     if(n !== newN){
        setN(n);
        doApiCall(); // <- very important
     }

  }, 500);

  return () => clearInterval(int_id);

}, []);
```

notice the condition inside the interval, `if (n...`

Problem is that it always sees `n` as 0 (initial value), I guess it's because the function is cached..

Is there a way to get the current n value at the time the interval function is executed?

Comment: You can consider implementing the `useInterval()` hook - You can read more about this problem and the `useInterval()` hook in Dan Abramov's Overreacted blog [here](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/)

Comment: Pass `n` to the dependency list of `useEffect`

Comment: But I don't want for the effect to run every time n changes

Comment: @Alex But *why* don't you want to update the interval callback when `n` updates? Is `n` being changed more then every 500ms? This would causes a interval clock reset due to the clear/re-add, thus never invoking the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Using [`refs`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).
A ref is a stable container which works very much like a state variable but does not cause re-render. Its value is persisted accross renders.

```
const [n, setN] = useSTate(0);
const nRef = useRef(n);

// sync value of nRef with n
useEffect(() => { nRef.current = n }, [n]);

useEffect(() => {

  const int_id = setInterval(() => {
    const currentN = nRef.current; // get the current value of `n` through the ref
    const newN = getN(...);

    if(currentN !== newN){
      setN(currentN); 
      doApiCall(); // <- very important
    }

  }, 500);

  return () => clearInterval(int_id);

}, []);
```

Another approach could be passing `n` to the dependency list and then keeping track of first render using another ref. This ref could be something like

```
const firsRender = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {

  const int_id = setInterval(() => {
    if(firstRender.current){
      firstRender.current = false;
      const newN = getN(...);

      if(currentN !== newN){
        setN(currentN); 
        doApiCall(); // <- very important
      }
    }
  }, 500);

  return () => clearInterval(int_id);
}, [n]);
```

Comment: Why you update nRef.current = n inside effect an not in the body of the function?

Comment: @OktayYuzcan A good rule of thumb is to keep the rendering function itself side-effect free. So therefore you would update the `ref` inside a `useEffect`. In this scenario updating the `ref` as part of the render function wouldn't significantly change the behaviour. But sticking to the best practice doesn't hurt.

Comment: Yes. Except intializing, anything you do with a ref, should be done in useEffect. It does not play well with concurrent mode. You can google it up. Above code is good to go, wherever you update the ref but in certain cases it can be problematic. Sometimes, ref might get updated multiple times without any changes to the DOM. Because a render can happen without a commit (in concurrent mode)
It is out of scope of this question but you will definitely find it online.